# Get attribute values with HTML::PullParser

Tags: perl, parsing, perl-module

I wrote a piece of Perl code to parse an HTML file and list its tags with their attibutes :

```
my $lo_parser = HTML::PullParser->new(
    file => $gs_html_doc,
    start => 'event, tagname, @attr',
    ) or die "Error: $!";
$lo_parser->unbroken_text(1);

while (my $iY_token = $lo_parser->get_token)
{
    my $ls_event = $iY_token->[0]; # always "start"
    my $ls_name = $iY_token->[1];
    my @ly_attr = $iY_token->[2];

    print "$ls_name:\n";
    foreach (0 .. $#ly_attr)
    {
        print "- $ly_attr[$_]\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

It works fine, but I don't know how to get the VALUES of the different attributes. None of the sites I found about HTML::PullParser gave me the answer.

Could anybody help, please?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `@ly_attr` should contain a hash reference, shouldn't it?

Comment: It doesn't seem to, hence my perplexity.

As far as I can say, it contains the name of the 1st attribute (and I just realise the other ones are missing, in fact).

Comment: Well, I finaly found a solution, using 'attr' instead of '@attr' in the parser definition.

Should I delete my question?

Comment: @JNM: No. Write it up as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, I didn't find the solution to make the parser work when declared with "@attr".

Yet, with a slightly different approach, I finally got what I want.

```
my $lo_parser = HTML::PullParser->new(
    file => $gs_html_doc,
    start => 'event, tagname, attr',
    ) or die "Error: $!";
$lo_parser->unbroken_text(1);

while (my $iY_token = $lo_parser->get_token)
{
    my $ls_event = $iY_token->[0]; # always "start"
    my $ls_name = $iY_token->[1];
    my $lH_attr = $iY_token->[2];

    print "$ls_name:\n";
    foreach (keys %{$lH_attr})
    {
        print "- $_ = $lH_attr->{$_} = \n";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```